# Microsoft Graphi API counting messages received for the previous day

Tags: https, microsoft-graph-api

I want to get the total messages received for the previous day, but the request returns the totals messages for all time and not just for the previous day.

I tried a couple differnt ways.

This uri times out:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/mailxbox@micsoft.com/messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime eq '{{formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),-1),'yyyy-MM-dd')}}'&?$count=true
```

This uri gets the total email count for all time, not just yesterday:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/mailbox@microsoft.com/messages?$count=true&?search="received:yesterday"
```

I also tried switch $count to put before and after the filter/search with no success.

I also believe there is a reporting endpoint for the api, but I do not have permissions to it, hence I am trying this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With using filter query parameter and `$count=true`

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/messages?$filter=receivedDateTime ge 2023-03-01T00:00:00Z and receivedDateTime lt 2023-03-02T00:00:00Z&$select=id&$count=true
```

result

```
{
    "@odata.count": 2,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "AAMk...",
        },
        {
            "id": "AAMk...",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this appears to have worked!